# How to tell height of paragraph in OpenXML?

Tags: c#, xslt, ms-word, openxml

I'm generating an MS Word document from user data. The data is placed in a container which is serialized to XML, and the resulting XML is converted to OpenXML using XSLT. There are a few minor changes done programmatically in C# to generate the Word document, as they can't be done with XSLT.

There is a user requirement that an item be placed completely on one page without any associated data being split onto another page. Sometimes one item will fill up an entire page, and sometimes I can fit three or four items on one page (I need to insert a separator (horizontal rule) between items that fit on the same page.)

Is there a way to determine whether or not one item or OpenXML paragraph will fit entirely on the "current" page? This can be either via C# or XSLT, and I can work something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way this can be reliably done is to actually *render the output,* including all of the font sizes, bolding, kerning and all that.  Which means you have to do the pagination in Word, and then save it back to the OpenXML.